# Done Button not working in FlipsideViewCOntroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm updating my app form xib files to a storyboard. I'm also upgrading the app to iOS 7.
I have a two page app, like a Utility app. I can create e segue to flip to the second page. However when hitting the done button nothing happens. I've tried several things (the suggestions on SO too) but without result.

Ik started a new project (Utility) an compared the code for the segue and for dismissing the FlipsideViewController. In my project and the new one the code is the same.

I placed an NSLog call in the flipsideViewControllerDidFinish method but no effect.

I am out of ideas, please help.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but did you connect the done button to an IBOutlet that invokes `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish`?

Answer (score 0):

While posting I got a (last) Idea. I had to check if the segue identifier was correct.
And it wasn't. So I corrected it and it works like a charm.

Thank you.